# Best way to deal with creation of user account after successful purchase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering what might be the best way to create a user account once a successful payment is made, this is my app's flow at the moment:

- User selects a package
- User checksout via paypal express
- On return I have the user's details including email address (and so a confirm order button will then finish the process)

Should I include a password and password-confirm field and use 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :user' in my Order model, or, would it be better to let them simply confirm the order (to keep things simple) and just generate a random password and then email that to them with their order confirmation/invoice via observers (and perhaps force a password change on first visit).

What do you think is better?
*(I'm trying to keep in mind things like security/risk of emails going into spam folder etc)*

Any thoughts on the matter? I guess both are ok - but posting just in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that you offer both.  Once you implement it you will see which way your users gravitate to and then you can select one based on their habits.

You want to make it the most enjoyable experience for your users so really you have to give them what they want.  Depending upon your audience and product you could argue either way.

It might be as simple as having a check box that says "create user account automatically and email the details"

In the end it's the customer you have to satisfy so let them choose initially.  The'll tell you what they want.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Wavedrop, thanks for the answer. I think we have to factor in email being flagged as spam, Yahoo is notorious for censoring emails - they don't even go in a junk or spam folder! So I think I might go with the first option of letting them set the password themselves... at least that way they can access their account even if they don't get the order confirmation. Thanks for your input.